# Single integral of multivariable piecewise function with conditions depending on other conditions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, piecewise-continuity

This is a follow-up question to [Integrating multivariate piecewise function where one condition involves multiple variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3354265/integrating-multivariate-piecewise-function-where-one-condition-involves-multipl)

In the case where a condition depends on *another* condition, how would you go about evaluating the integral? For example, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) dy$ where:

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
g(x,y) & -y \leq x \leq y, 0 < y < \infty \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer was given to me by a teaching assistant from my home university.*

It would help to first visualize the domain over where $f(x, y)$ is nonzero (or, in this case, equivalently, where $f(x, y) = g(x, y)$) by [sketching a diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmdST.jpg). Then it follows from the diagram that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, y) dy = \begin{cases}
  \int_{-x}^{\infty} g(x, y) dy & x < 0 \\
  \int_x^{\infty} g(x, y) dy & x \geq 0
\end{cases}$$